# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, python-requests

[when running test i'm getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyhh.png)
earlier i'm using `python-requests v2.2.1`.so,
i have upgraded `python-requests` to `v2.14.2` but still i'm facing the same issue.
`HeaderDict(requests.packages.urllib3._collections.HTTPHeaderDict):
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'`
check the below result:

```html
======================================================================
ERROR: rest_blog.tests.test_views (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: rest_blog.tests.test_views
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vamsi/PycharmProjects/ReminderToDo/rest_blog/tests/test_views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    class HeaderDict(requests.packages.urllib3._collections.HTTPHeaderDict):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reinstalling requests or upgrading requests should solve the problem.

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```